# jQuery - Append text as a list

Tags: jquery

I want to append value as a list.But somehow I am not able to do that.

When I try to add it, It just gets overlapped to other list.When I add CSS to get rid of that overlapping, then I am not able to take click event.You can see in below picture.

[image]

Here is the code I am using to append the values as list:

```
$.getJSON('path to json', function(data) {

        $.each( data.markers, function(i, value) { 
            var radlat1 = Math.PI * position.coords.latitude/180;
            var radlat2 = Math.PI * value.latitude/180;
            var radlon1 = Math.PI * position.coords.longitude/180;
            var radlon2 = Math.PI * value.longitude/180;
            var theta = position.coords.longitude-value.longitude;
            var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
            var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
            dist = Math.acos(dist);
            dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
            dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
            dist = dist * 1.609344;
            if(dist<10){
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.latitude, value.longitude);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: "text "+value.longitude
            });

            $(".newclasscheck").append("<li>"+value.content+"</li>");
            }

        });
});
```

And I php code is as follow where I am appending this :

```
    <ul class="newclasscheck"></ul>
                <ul class="check">
                <?php
                    foreach($result as $results)
                    {
                        $atag = "#filter-list-".$results->fax;
                        $results->wpsl_id;
                        $results->store.'<br/>'; 
                        $results->address.'<br/>'; 
                        $results->address2.'<br/>';
                        $results->city.'<br/>';
                        $results->state.'<br/>';
                        $results->country.'<br/>';
                        $results->description.'<br/>';
                        $results->phone.'<br/>';
                        $posts[] = array('latitude'=> $results->lat, 'longitude'=> $results->lng, 'area'=>$atag, 'content'=> $results->store); 
                ?>
                <li class="area-element <?php echo $results->fax;  ?>"><div><p><strong class="lstore <?php echo $results->store; ?>" data-value-lat="<?php echo $results->lat; ?>" data-value-lng="<?php echo $results->lng; ?>"><?php echo $results->store; ?></strong><span class='wpsl-street'><?php echo $results->address;?></span><span class='wpsl-street'><?php echo $results->address2;?></span><?php echo $results->city ."". $results->state ."".$results->zip ; ?></p><span><a href="?page_id=417&store_id=<?php echo $results->wpsl_id ?>" class='more-details'>More details</a></span></div></li>  
                <?php 
                    } 
        ?>
```

What should I do to print out same list as `check` class is having? Where am I lacking ?

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Its not possible for me to show on a fiddle cz I am using wordpress and above list is coming from the database.

Comment: Did you try using `clear:both` style for your `ul`s to prevent overlapping?

Comment: Yes .. I have just tried after your comment.But It did not work out ...

Comment: Is it possible to see your webpage? Might need to debug..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65737/discussion-between-arincool-and-twix).